# The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager

Tags: entity-framework, refresh, repository-pattern

I am getting this error while executing "ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity)" in my Entity Framework using Repository pattern.

I tried executing this after and before executing the query, but it gives the error on both occasions.

What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: There are two possible reasons in the exception message. Without code we can't do better.

Comment: Could you please guide me about those two possible reasons? Its really difficult for me to extract code to paste here, because I work on remote connections, and copy-paste is quite a daunting task there, also no access to external sites.. so it would be better if you guide me those two reasons, and I will check within my code.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is that `entity` in not attached to the context.

Comment: How did you get the `entity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be either that:

- The entity has not been attached to the context, or
- You have not applied Add() or AddObject().
- If you have applied AddObject() at some point, you need to Detach() the entity, not the entry.